# How to increase a grid world's size by 1000 times

Tags: python

I'm using a program in which I have to input the environment's map. The input form looks like this.

```
self.map=[   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I want to increase the size of the given structure by thousand times and maintain the form of the structure. After increasing the structure size will be 18000x6000. The code looks like [this](https://github.com/okkhoy/rlglue-python3-codec/blob/master/examples/mines-sarsa-example/sample_mines_environment.py)

Can someone suggest me a way to achieve this or any alternate way.

Comment: Please post if I need to add anymore information. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use Python's lists (numpy's arrays are better for large matrices) you could use

```
repeatfactor = 1000
mat = self.map  # copy reference, not data
m = len(mat)
n = len(mat[0])
newmatrix = [[mat[r % m][c % n] 
    for c in range(n * repeatfactor)]
    for r in range(m * repeatfactor)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `np.repeat` twice--once in each axis. Not the prettiest, but should work. So something like this:

```
map_array = np.array(self.map)
map_array = np.repeat(map_array, 1000, axis=0)
map_array = np.repeat(map_array, 1000, axis=1)
```